# Installing product 'collective.examples.userdata' gives "error: docs/HISTORY.txt: No such file or directory"

Tags: plone

I am trying to try out collective.examples.userdata (by adding collective.examples.userdata to the eggs section of my buildout) but it's giving an error:

```
Getting distribution for 'collective.examples.userdata'.
error: docs/HISTORY.txt: No such file or directory
```

I have looked at the git repo and there is a docs/HISTORY.txt, so I am not sure why this would happen.

Comment: Which version of collective.examples.userdata are you using? I quickly tested an install of v 0.3.1 in a Plone-4.3.2, works fine.

Comment: Ok, v. 0.4 throws this error, most likely `MANIFEST.in` needs to be adjusted, please open a ticket, TIA.

Comment: Open the issue there: https://github.com/collective/collective.examples.userdata/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the **release is broken**.

Often times due to the complexity of releasing a package, mistakes are made. To avoid errors like this one, release managers can use the [check-manifest](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/check-manifest) utility which matches files in the `sdist` to files in the MANIFEST.in file and reports the results.